# Loop in vba which will go through all sheets and get data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to see if somebody can show me a cycle in VBA Excel that will do the following action:

Let's say that I have a variouse unknown number of sheets with unknown names and than one final sheed as a "result sheet"  I would like this cycle to go trought all other sheets except the last one and to grab from them the Field which have a field name: "Company Name"  and to sort all that names one after another starting from the first one in the last "Result sheet"

and the name of the last sheet will be always te same Result Sheet, so that name might be used as an exception in case if it is needed.

Thaks.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I don't have Excel to test, and you are asking me to make it for you without even trying. I will give you a little piece that should put you in the right way.

This copies A1 from each sheet into the sheet Result sheet.

```
Dim Sh1 As WorkSheet, Sh2 As WorkSheet, R As Integer
Set Sh1 = Sheets("Result sheet")
R = 1
For Each Sh2 In WorkSheets
  If Sh2.Name <> "Result sheet" Then
    Sh1.Cells(R, 1) = Sh2.Cells(1, 1)
    R = R + 1
  End If
Next Sh2
```

At the end you end up with the data in Sh1, and you can play with Sh2.Sort() to sort it the way you want.